# MacBook Pro asks to reset password, but neither keyboard nor mousepad are working

Tags: keyboard, password, login, startup

When I turned on my MacBook pro, I saw a screen titled: "Reset Password", and I was asked to choose between three alternatives: I forgot my password, My password doesn't work, The keyboard doesn't work. [Here's a photo of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm9g6.jpg).

I have no idea why this screen was shown. I remember my password quite vividly, and all I did was turn on the laptop.

However, this is not the worst part. The worst part is that the computer doesn't react to either the keyboard or the mousepad. I'd choose "the keyboard doesn't work", except the keyboard doesn't work and therefore I can't choose this option...

Computer: MacBook Pro (mid 2012)
OS: macOS Catalina, v. 10.15 (possibly 10.15.1, I don't remember if I upgraded)

EDIT: I'd like to clarify the statement "my mousepad doesn't work". When I move my finger on the mousepad, the cursor follows the movement on the screen, however when I click in order to choose an option or hit one of the buttons "Next" or "Restart" at the bottom of the screen, no action takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem this way.

1. Turned off the computer manually by holding down the power button.
2. Attached an external mousetrack (Apple Magic Mouse 2) by USB.
3. Turned on the computer in recovery mode, by holding down the Command + R keys simultaneously while starting the computer, and releasing only when the Apple logo appeared.
4. When the recovery screen appeared, I used the Apple menu on the top left corner to restart the computer. It wasn't enough to tap the mousetrack in order to select the desired menu item, I had to forcefully press down on its surface.
5. The restart proceeded normally. Hurrah!